# Python - Fabric - Getting files

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, get, fabric

I am trying to write a simple python code with fabric to transfer a file from one host to another using the get() function although I keep getting error message:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:PythonsScripts$ fab get:'/tmp/test','/tmp/test'
[hostname] Executing task 'get'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
   *args, **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 387, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 277, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/e0126914/Desktop/PYTHON/PythonsScripts/fabfile.py", line 128, in get
    get('/tmp/test','/tmp/test') ***This line repeats many times then last error below***
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My current code is:

```
from fabric.api import *
from getpass import getpass
from fabric.decorators import runs_once

env.hosts = ['hostname']
env.port = '22'
env.user = 'parallels'
env.password="password"


def abc(remote_path, local_path):
    abc('/tmp/test','/tmp/')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fabric.api.get`](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get) already is a method. When you perform `from fabric.api import *` you are importing `fabric`'s `get`. You should rename your `get` function to avoid conflict.

From inside the `abc` function, you need to call `get`

```
def abc(p1,p2):
    get(p1, p2)
```

EDIT:
When executing functions through fabric, the arguments are passed through the command line
ie. `$ fab abc:string1,string2`

Comment: I tried changing the get function to "abc" although I am still getting the same error:"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 387, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 277, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: abc() takes exactly 2 arguments"

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I tried to use ***fab abc:'/tmp/test','/tmp/'*** and also *** and also tried with double quotes and no qutes over each string. Although, I am getting error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" Thanks for your help and any further suggestions @Yash Mehrotra

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the latest formatted code.

Comment: I've updated the question with my current code and errors

Comment: Happy to help, also please mark this answer as accepted so that it will help other developers in the future :)

Comment: Happy to help, also please upvote/accept the answer so that it can help other people with similar problem.